# What is models.common.C3 in yolov5 model?

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolov5

[Yolo model summary][1]

Also can someone explain the values in arguments column
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/weBPt.png

Answer (score 1):

I am studying the yolov5 architecture right now, so do not take my answer as absolute truth, but for my understanding the C3 Layer is a CSP bottleneck that includes 3 convolutional layers. Essentially it does a Conv on the input tensor and it concats the result to the same tensor passed through a convolution AND a series of bottleneck layers with e=1. Then the whole thing is passed again through a Convolution layer. CSP stands for Cross Stage Partial layer.

As per the first column, it is used in the forward function of the model to understand which tensor to use as the input value of each layer. The majority of the layers has '-1', meaning they take the last layer's output before them as their input, but there are Concat layers that take different levels as input to recreate the PANet architecture in the neck.
For further questions, I suggest you to ask in the Yolov5 github issues section, as they are often quick to give you answers.